# Digital sample and hold synced with a CLK

Tags: digital-logic, clock, sample-and-hold

So I though this should be pretty straightforward, but apparently it's not.

Supposed we have a digital async input signal and a CLK. I want to sample the given input signal on every rising (or falling edge) of the CLK signal and output the value of the input signal when CLK event occured. I do not care about the intermediate states. I just want to have a signal that replicates the state of the input signal at a clock event and keeps that state until the next clock even.

Here is a diagram in case I am not clear enough:

[image]

I am sure that there is a simple IC (possibly from the 74xx series) that does exactly this, however, I cannot seem to come across one.

Thank you very much!

Comment: You need a faster clock for the input signal you have shown.  Reference "Nyquist sampling theorem"... satisfy Nyquist and you should be ok.  I am not sure if there is a discrete device that will do it for you.

Comment: Please note: The input signal CAN change its state several times during a CLK half period (i.e. it can be much faster than CLK).

Comment: I do not want to satisfy Nyquist, as I don't care in reproducing the original signal, I just want to sample and know at given intervals of CLK what it's value was (I don't care about interim values between CLK events).

Comment: Use a D-type flip flop like the 7474?

Comment: What if the input signal changes on the clock edge?  Is it a don't care such that it can be either 0 or 1 for your application?  Yeh, like @Finbarr said... if you don't care, just use a DFF (a non-transparent latch) and it will do what you are asking.

Comment: If the input signal changes exactly on CLK edge, either a 1 or 0 should be fine, as the input signal itself is generated by a random pattern generator.

Comment: So if you don't care about the integrity of measurement when sampling at a data edge AND the signal is a random signal, why bother reading it at all - why not just locally generate a random signal and ignore the remote random signal?

Answer (score 1):

A D latch will do exactly what you want. The prototypical version is the 7474, though there are plenty of other part numbers that group them into quads, octals, add output or clock enables etc.

Some of the comments discuss what happens when the data changes *on* a clock edge. There are three possible outcomes. The first two are that you get the data it was, or you get the data it changes to. One of these two is overwhelmingly likely.

However a third rare possibility is that you get an output that cannot be interpreted as a valid logic output. It may be a middle state between the highest valid '0' and the lowest valid '1' that persists for longer than the expected propagation delay (\$T_p\$), or it could be an otherwise valid state that changes spontaneously later than \$T_p\$. This is metastability, which can only occur if you violate the setup and hold times of the D-latch. It cannot be avoided, but it can be designed down to a vanishingly small probability of occurring, by ensuring that you wait long enough after the initial sampling edge before trying to use the data. The chance of a bad logic output persisting falls exponentially as the delay increases. This is commonly done by adding at least a second, and sometimes more, further latches in a pipeline after the initial one. With enough latency, the probability can be pushed down to 'once in 10x the age of the universe', by which time you can reasonably regard it as 'solved'.